cannot read property of "'CABAILITY_PLAY'" of null React Native
I am Integrated the Audio functionality with in the App using react-native-track-player the issue I was facing that App is not running When i Add this line in my (index.js) TrackPlayer.registerPlaybackService(() => playbackService); This is my code in PlaybackService file
 Event,
 RepeatMode,
} from "react-native-track-player"
import { PLAY_LIST_DATA } from "@/constants"

export async function setUpPlayer() {
 let isSetup = false
 try {
   await TrackPlayer.getActiveTrackIndex()
   isSetup = true
 } catch (error) {
   await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer()
   isSetup = true
 } finally {
   return isSetup
 }
}

export async function addTrackToPlayer() {
 await TrackPlayer.add(PLAY_LIST_DATA)
 await TrackPlayer.setRepeatMode(RepeatMode.Queue)
}
export async function playbackService() {
 TrackPlayer.addEventListener(Event.RemotePause, () => {
   TrackPlayer.pause()
 })
 TrackPlayer.addEventListener(Event.RemotePlay, () => {
   TrackPlayer.play()
 })
}

I have try getActiveTrackIndex() because getCurrentrack is replaced with it not found any proper solution for this

I have Fixed the issue by Adding this code in my playbackService file  await TrackPlayer.updateOptions({ android: { appKilledPlaybackBehavior: AppKilledPlaybackBehavior.StopPlaybackAndRemoveNotification, }, capabilities: [Capability.Play, Capability.Pause], compactCapabilities: [Capability.Play, Capability.Pause], progressUpdateEventInterval: 2, })

 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'CAPABILITY_PLAY' of null, js engine: hermes [Component Stack]

I got this error  "import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import TrackPlayer, { Capability, RatingType, RepeatMode } from 'react-native-track-player'
const setupPlayer = async () => {
await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer({
maxCacheSize: 1024 * 10,
})
await TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
ratingType: RatingType.Heart,
capabilities: [
Capability.Play,
Capability.Pause,
Capability.SkipToNext,
Capability.SkipToPrevious,
Capability.Stop,
],
})"in this code

any solution ??

Have you tried the solution which i have provided? @NuwanChamikara
